# Quartz Job can't call facebook Service ( Spring Social )

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-security, quartz-scheduler, spring-social-facebook

Im trying to call facebook API through my Quartz Job for automatically getting friends, posts, or newfeeds ... but I cant run through Job. I think I have wrong on SocialConfig. 
When i call facebookService from controller, it works normally.
Can you help me figure out this problem. Many thanks.

**SocialConfig**

```
public class SocialConfig {
@Value("${facebook.clientId}")
private String facebookClientId;

@Value("${facebook.clientSecret}")
private String facebookClientSecret;

@Inject
private DataSource dataSource;
@Bean
public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();
    registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(facebookClientId, facebookClientSecret));
    return registry;
}

@Bean
public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository() {
    JdbcUsersConnectionRepository repository = new JdbcUsersConnectionRepository(dataSource,
            connectionFactoryLocator(), Encryptors.noOpText());
    repository.setConnectionSignUp(new SimpleConnectionSignUp());
    return repository;
}
@Bean
@Scope(value="request", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.NO)
public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository() {
    User user = SecurityContext.getCurrentUser();
    return usersConnectionRepository().createConnectionRepository(user.getId());
}

@Bean
@Scope(value="session", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS) 
public Facebook facebook() {
    return connectionRepository().getPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class).getApi();
}
```

**Getting errors**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '**scopedTarget.facebook': Scope 'session' is not active for the current thread**; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:**No thread-bound request found**: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: **In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.**

I have tried RequestContextListener by adding in web.xml but it doesn't work.

**Calling from Job**.

```
@Override
protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
        throws JobExecutionException {
    try {
        ApplicationContextProvider appContext = new ApplicationContextProvider();
        FacebookService facebookService = appContext.getApplicationContext().getBean("facebookService", FacebookService.class);
      //##It shows error here##
        System.out.println("!!User: "+facebookService.getFacebookFriends().get(0).getName());
        //runMeTask.printMe();
        System.out.println("!!*****Quartz*****!!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
```

**Facebook Service**

```
public class FacebookService {
private Facebook facebook;

@Inject
public FacebookService(Facebook facebook) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
}
}

public Facebook getFacebook() {
    return facebook;
}

public void setFacebook(Facebook facebook) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
}
public List<Reference> getFacebookFriends() {
    // Get Friend List
    return getFacebook().friendOperations().getFriends();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution for this by following [Facebook4j](http://facebook4j.org/en/index.html)

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthAppId("app_id")
      .setOAuthAppSecret("app_secret")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("user_token")
      .setOAuthPermissions("email,publish_actions,public_profile, basic_info,  user_likes");
    FacebookFactory ff = new FacebookFactory(cb.build());
    // Generate facebook instance.
    this.facebook = ff.getInstance();
```

The problem in here that when my job run and call Facebook API, it doesnt have user access token so when posting message to wall my quartz job doest permission to post.